# Question on an unbalanced Wheatstone bridge

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Let,

P/Q = R/S in the usual sense of a Wheatstone bridge where PQRS are resistances.
Then we know that the potential between midpoints of PQ and RS are equal and there's no potential difference between the midpoints i.e. $V_b = 0$.

[image: Wheatstone bridge]

Now if it was
P/Q > R/S

It is said that potential between PQ is less than RS. And the bridge is unbalanced. How do you prove this inequality. I know the absense of proper images make it hard to grasp my question, but i tried my best to explain it with words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the left branch of the bridge. The total resistance is $P + Q$, so the current is:

$$ I_{left} = \frac{V}{P+Q} $$

The voltage drop across $Q$ is just $V = IR$, so the voltage at the $PQ$ midpoint is:

$$ V_{PQ} = V_{in}\frac{Q}{P+Q} $$

We argue in the same way for the right hand branch to get the corresponding equation:

$$ V_{RS} = V_{in}\frac{S}{R+S} $$

So the bridge voltage $V_b$ is given by:

$$ V_b = V_{PQ} - V_{RS} = V_{in}\left(\frac{Q}{P+Q} - \frac{S}{R+S}\right) \tag{1} $$

When the bridge is balanced $V_b = 0$. If we set $V_b = 0$ in equation (1) we get:

$$ \frac{Q}{P+Q} = \frac{S}{R+S} $$

and rearranging this gives:

$$ \frac{P}{Q} = \frac{R}{S} $$

Now suppose $V_b \lt 0$. If we put this into equation (1) we get:

$$ V_{in}\left(\frac{Q}{P+Q} - \frac{S}{R+S}\right) \lt 0 $$

or:

$$ \frac{Q}{P+Q} \lt \frac{S}{R+S} $$

and rearranging this gives:

$$ \frac{R}{S} \lt \frac{P}{Q} $$

Comment: Although i needed a proof other way around this perfectly answered my question. Thank you very much  i accepted ur ans